# Caching in a JSP Spring MVC application

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I am a beginner in developing JSP/web applications and I've gotten to the point where I'm thinking about implementing some kind of caching in my application but I don't exactly know how to do this. I've worked on and Android app before we I did caching and just saved data to SQLite and did a quick SQL count query to the server's table to see if the count returned was the same to what was in SQLite. If it was then no new data has been updated on the server, if that count was different then add it to the SQLite table (normally this was a small number of record increases). So that was quite easy and self explanatory.

However, I don't know what rules to follow when doing this in a web application that uses JSP and the Spring MVC framework. I am also using Tomcat as my test sever. Is there some location where I can save things and grab them later? Or is this not the appropriate way to do things? Someone who has more experience than myself, give me some advice or wisdom. I would certainly appreciate it and would love to learn more on this subject! Also please don't mark this question as nonconstructive. This application is for work and needs to be completed in a certain time frame. I am aware there are some nifty tools and helpers out there such as Squid.

Comment: Look for ehcache and infinispan.

Comment: So I pretty much need to data cache result returned from the database. I would be storing those results on the server somehow? Tomcat in my case. So next time the web page is navigated to and the user selects a certain option from a drop down, if nothing has changed in the real DB table in terms of count, then I just want to grab my data from the tomcat server?

Comment: A cache library is independent of the application server. The fact you use Tomcat or JBoss or GlassFish or another is irrelevant for the cache library, unless the application server already ships a cache library.

Comment: One of my main questions is where is the cache data to be stored? Say someone selects an option from a dropdown and the results are returned from a DB. How do I store those results such that the person can close the web browser, reopen it, select the same dropdown option but this time it retrieves the saved data rather than pulling from the DB again. Where am I retrieving this data from? A .Ser file?

Comment: Found an excellent article while searching for answers: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2072734/open-source-tools/j2ee-object-caching-frameworks.html

Answer (score 1):

check out ehcache 
http://java-success.blogspot.in/2013/10/ehcache-beginner-level-tutorial.html
http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/07/04/hibernate-ehcache-configuration-tutorial/ this tutorials might help you.

you can save object in application context map or create a simple map in servlet and intialise it d uring servlet init and destory it when done.